# Azure DownloadText and UploadText C#

Tags: c#, css, azure, blob

I'm new to Azure and I'm having a strange problem.

I have a web application were the user is able to modify and save a `.css` file, that later is included in the page.

I'm doing this by creating CloudBlob instance, calling `.DownloadText()`, downloading the current css, modifying it and then uploading it again with `.UploadText()`

The problem is that the css doesn't get interpreted by Chrome or Firefox, but it works in Internet Explorer. Meaning that the css file gets downloaded when is included in the page and I can see the changes with Developer Tools or Firebug, but they don't get applied in the page (but in IE works).

Any help it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the content type to text/css?

```
blob.Properties.ContentType = @"text/css";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the content type of the response. I think i should be text/css